# Ruby - "undefined method 'at'"

Tags: ruby

```
class Book
def isBook()
    return true
end

def initialize(isbn, userID)
    @isbn = isbn
    @userID = userID
end

def ==(var)
    if(var.isbn == @isbn && var.userID == @userID)
        return true
    end

    return false
end

def print()
    "ISBN: %{@isbn}\nWypozyczono przez: %{@userID}"
end
end 

class BookList
def initialize()
    @arr = Array.new()
end

def add(book)
    if(book.isBook())
        @arr.push(book)
    end
end

def at(var)
    @arr[var].print()
end
end 

booklist = BookList.new()
print booklist
booklist.add(Book.new(1231231231231, "d_zeglen"))

print BookList.at(0)
```

I don't know where did I made mistake. When I try to run this program, ruby prints into console:

```
undefined method 'at' for BookList:Class (No method error)
```

Anybody got idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#at` is an *instance method* of the instances of the class `BookList`, not a *class method*. Thus below will work

```
print booklist.at(0)
```

Here is the code :-

```
class Book
  def isBook()
    return true
  end

  def initialize(isbn, userID)
    @isbn = isbn
    @userID = userID
  end

  def ==(var)
    if(var.isbn == @isbn && var.userID == @userID)
      return true
    end

    return false
  end

  def print()
    "ISBN: %{@isbn}\nWypozyczono przez: %{@userID}"
  end
end 

class BookList
  def initialize()
    @arr = Array.new()
  end

  def add(book)
    if(book.isBook())
      @arr.push(book)
    end
  end

  def at(var)
    @arr[var].print()
  end
end 

booklist = BookList.new()
print booklist
booklist.add(Book.new(1231231231231, "d_zeglen"))

print booklist.at(0)
# >> #<BookList:0xa013de4>ISBN: %{@isbn}
# >> Wypozyczono przez: %{@userID}
```